# How to create a new environment that finds and replaces text patterns?

Tags: l3regex, listofitems

I'm trying to create an environment, which would find and replace certain patterns in its body and would not conflict with other environment that would possible include it. One of the possible usage scenario may look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{foo}
a -> b \\ c -> \LaTeX
\end{foo}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Here, my `foo` environment should replace `->` with `\to` (in my real case I have many more patterns). Another possible usage, this time without `gather`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
a -> \textbf{\TeX}
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

How would you do this? (I would prefer to use `\regex_replace_all` from `expl3`, but it's not a requirement.)

Comment: Are you willing to entertain a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: Nope, Lua is not an option here, sorry

Comment: I wouldn't do the replacement during the tex compilation but either with an external script or with lualatex when reading the file.

Comment: As a thought (which someone else can develop or describe as 'not feasible'), make the `-` character active (yes, I know that might be a bad idea), and look for either `>` next (in which case, replace it with the output of `\to`), or not, in which case replace it with a literal `-`. But it is probably easier, as @UlrikeFischer said, to pre-process the source file.

Comment: And since I re-read the question, and saw that you have many patterns, I would suggest a Perl/Python/Awk/Sed script to do the work. A do-nothing environment should be able to be used as a guard on the script, so that it only applies where you want.

Comment: Any good text editor should be able to do this.  Why use LaTeX?

Comment: @JohnKormylo you may be surprised, but I find it more convenient to write `->` instead of `\mapsto`

Comment: `LaTeX3` has a regex machinery...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See End of Answer for General Case with Multiple Substitutions

Is something along these lines what you seek?  Here, I use a `listofitems` approach that uses the to-be-replaced text as the list separator of the input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,amsmath}
\setsepchar{->}
\def\reptext{$\to$}
\newcommand\replace[1]{\readlist\pathlist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\pathlist[]{\ifnum\zcnt=1\else\reptext\fi\z}}
\begin{document}
\replace{a -> b \\ c -> \LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the to-be-replaced and replacement texts can be part of the macro invocation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,amsmath}
\newcommand\replace[3]{\setsepchar{#1}%
  \readlist\pathlist{#3}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\pathlist[]{\ifnum\zcnt=1\else#2\fi\z}}
\begin{document}
\replace{->}{$\to$}{a -> b \\ c -> \LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

...or an environment invocation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,amsmath,environ}
\NewEnviron{replace}[2]{\setsepchar{#1}%
  \readlist\pathlist{\BODY}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\pathlist[]{\ifnum\zcnt=1\else#2\fi\z}}
\begin{document}
\begin{replace}{->}{$\to$}
  a -> b \\ c -> \LaTeX
\end{replace}
\end{document}
```

**GENERAL CASE WITH MULTIPLE SUBSTITUTIONS**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,amsmath,environ}
\newcommand\defxx[2]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#2}}
\newtoks\septoks
\NewEnviron{replace}[2]{%
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist*\pretext{#1}%
  \readlist*\posttext{#2}%
  \septoks{}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\pretext[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\else\global\septoks\expandafter{\the\septoks||}\fi%
    \global\septoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\the\expandafter\septoks\z}%
  }%
  \expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\the\septoks}%
  \readlist\pathlist{\BODY}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\pathlist[]{\ifnum\zcnt=1\else
    \foreachitem\zz\in\pretext[]{%
      \defxx\zzz{\pretext[\zzcnt]}%
      \defxx\zzzz{\pathlistsep[\zcnt-1]}%
      \ifx\zzz\zzzz\posttext[\zzcnt]\fi
    }\fi\z%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{replace}{          <-,   ->,               Z}
               {$\leftarrow$,$\to$,\textbf{Hi Mom!}}
  a -> b \\ c <- \LaTeX{} -> Z
\end{replace}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. How might this setup have to be adapted to make it work inside a `gather` environment?

Comment: @Mico Since `gather` is (if I recall) a math environment, I instead used `\NewEnviron` to create an environment form not tied to math mode (see edit).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but my _real_ use case is much more complicated: I want to replace many other patterns in the text, not just `->`. Or I missed the idea of stacking multiple `replace` environments one into another? Maybe you can extend your answer with an example where `->` and, say, `<-` are replaced.

Comment: @yegor256 Please see the supplement to my answer for the general case solution.

Answer (score 8):

While the OP has stated in a comment that a LuaLaTeX-based solution is "not an option" for their use case, others may still find it instructive to learn how such a solution may look like.

The solution consists of (a) a Lua function, called `foosub`, that performs the desired string substitution(s) -- observe that it's entirely possible to set up several string substitutions -- and (b) a LaTeX environment, called `foo`, which executes the following instructions:

- Upon entry, assign the `foosub` function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, to make it act like a pre-processor on the input stream. That way, e.g, `<->` is replaced by `\leftrightarrow` *before* TeX gets to perform its usual processing steps.
- Upon exit, remove `foosub` from the `process_input_buffer` callback.

The only restriction I'm aware of on the applicability of this code (other than the ability to compile the document under LuaLaTeX) is that the `foo` environment must include the `gather` environment, rather than the other way around.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % <-- Important, to avoid interactions 
                          %     with code in 'umsa.fd' file.

\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment

%% Lua-side code: Lua function to perform the string substitutions
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
   function foosub ( s )
      s = s:gsub ( "<%->" , "\\leftrightarrow " )
      s = s:gsub ( "%->"  , "\\rightarrow " )
      s = s:gsub ( "<%-"  , "\\leftarrow " )
      return ( s )
   end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code: LaTeX environment called "foo"
\newenvironment{foo}%
  {\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
     "process_input_buffer", foosub , "foosub" )}}%
  {\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( 
     "process_input_buffer", "foosub" )}}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
\begin{gather}
  a ->  b \\ 
  c <-  d \\
  e <-> \text{\LaTeX}
\end{gather}
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```